# Make a dynamic and depended list from worksheets

Tags: excel, offset, excel-indirect

I have worksheets named Day 1 and Day 2 and a worksheet named "Workbook Master" where I would like to have three drop-down lists;

1. The list at Cell C2 should get values from cell C10 from the Worksheets named "Day ".
2. The list at Cell C3, should get values from cell C11 from the Worksheets named "Day " AND that corresponds to Cell C2. (Unique values)
3. The list at Cell C4 should the values from C13 from the Worksheets named "Day" and that corresponds to Cell C2 and C3 (Unique values).

It should search through all Worksheets that starts with the name "Day"

I have used Google heavly and searched on "dynamic list", dynamic list worksheet" and got on the trail to read more about INDIRECT and OFFSET.

You can find the Excel file, [here](http://www.filedropper.com/joker_1)

Comment: I'm finding this really hard to follow and I'm not downloading your workbook to help put together the pieces here. Can you create a minimal example of what you are trying to do like *"I have two worksheets named `Day 1` and `Day 2`. On my third worksheet when I put the number `2` into `C2` I want to get the value from cell `C11` in the worksheet that corresponds to that number, so `'Day 2'!$C$11`"* (as an example). From that smaller example and answer perhaps then you can start piecing your other two questions together?

Comment: Thanks for the good information, @JNevill! I have updated my post, is it more clear for you what I'm after?

Comment: Sounds like you want a "cascading or dependent drop-down list". Take a look at [this site](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/) or [this site](https://www.exceltip.com/data-tools/dependent-data-validation.html) for guidance to see if it fits your situation.

Comment: The last link was a great site for information. However, my biggest issue is that my data is not in one sheet, it's in many.  When I try to make a dynamic range name, it just captures the worksheet name I'm in. 

How can I make a dynamic range, where the value is locked to one or more cells, but has a "wildcare" worksheet name referance - in this case, "Day"